# How to use a sequence table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, oracle11g

```
public String getJobNumber() {
              String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd";
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
              Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000000");
              return sdf.format(calendar.getTime()) +
                      numberFormat.format(getId()) + jobNumber;
              }
```

I need a sequence table to keep track of the id of a table Header which contains a field jobNumber. jobNumber is in a format like 20130816**0000001**XXXXXX.

I thought I could use the id on save (but it is not saved yet), to generate the jobNumber.

I got the exception :

```
 org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.test.model.Header.jobNumber
```

How can I use a table (or something else) to keep track of the last id?

The program should run on both MySQL and Oracle 11g DB. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table to contain your counter. Each time you need a new value, start another, very short transaction, which will get the value of the counter from the table, increment it, save it back in the table, and return it. Then generate your job number from this counter and save it into your entity.

If you often generate such job numbers, then you could use a better technique, like a hilo algorithm, or a technique which increments the counter by 100 and keeps the 100 next counter values in a thread-safe cache in memory.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of code for the thread safe counter loaded in cache please? I think that if the application goes down, I'll lose the information if not stored in a DB. For MySQL, the HI-Lo strategy would not work.

Comment: That's left as an exercise. Do it only if really necessary. The cache is not meant to replace the database. It's meant to avoid goind to the database too often. For example, first time you get a number, you go to the database, find 150, and increment it to 200. You then return 150. Next times, you return 151, 152, etc. until 199. Then you go back to the database to reserve the next slot of 50 values. If the application goes down you'll always restart from the value in the database.